# Add Facebook login button in your login page in c# mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement in my application to add the Facebook login button through which user can Authenticate through Facebook credentials.

I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

My requirement is to add a facebook button in my login page, not on default login page which MVC provides.

I found one helpful thing, but it's throwing an exception
PFB the code which I am referring

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private Uri RedirectUri
        {
            get
            {
                var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
                uriBuilder.Query = null;
                uriBuilder.Fragment = null;
                uriBuilder.Path = Url.Action("FacebookCallback");
                return uriBuilder.Uri;
            }
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return View("Login");
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Facebook()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = "444195149059600",
                client_secret = "89223ca2d87cc4a741000d5c1ea57694",
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "email" // Add other permissions as needed
            });

            return Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
        }

        public ActionResult FacebookCallback(string code)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "444195149059600",
                client_secret = "89223ca2d87cc4a741000d5c1ea57694",
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
                code = code
            });

            var accessToken = result.access_token;

            // Store the access token in the session for farther use
            Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

            // update the facebook client with the access token so 
            // we can make requests on behalf of the user
            fb.AccessToken = accessToken;

            // Get the user's information
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me?fields=first_name,middle_name,last_name,id,email");
            string email = me.email;
            string firstname = me.first_name;
            string middlename = me.middle_name;
            string lastname = me.last_name;
            
            // Set the auth cookie
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting some error in Actionresult Facebook(). How can I solve it?

Comment: Show which line throwing error and what exception(s) encountered there in detail.

Answer (score 1):

On your view you must be have like this;

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new {Model.ReturnUrl}))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                    @foreach (var p in loginProviders)
                    {
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="@p.AuthenticationType" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationType" title="Log in using your @p.Caption account">@p.AuthenticationType</button>
                    }
                </p>
            </div>
        }
```

I assumed you install OWIN to your application. So on your startup class

```
      public partial class Startup
            {

                public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; set; }       
                public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
                {
         app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
                       appId: "",
                       appSecret: "");
}
    }
```

On your external login, you have method like this

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
            public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string provider, string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)
            {
                // Require that the user has already logged in via username/password or external login
                if (!await SignInManager.HasBeenVerifiedAsync())
                    return View("Error");
                return View(new VerifyCodeViewModel { Provider = provider, ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = rememberMe });
            }

[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
                return RedirectToAction("Login");

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation",
                        new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
        }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model,
        string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Manage");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` This helped me soooo much, THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Your link refers to MVC 5, if you use MVC 4 you should look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc

There are a few important differences between these versions.. And if you provide more information about the recieved error, it is easier to give a concrete hint about the underlying problem

Bst rgrds

Comment: i am facing error in                                                                               var fb = new FacebookClient();
            var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = "444195149059600",
                client_secret = "89223ca2d87cc4a741000d5c1ea57694",
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "email" // Add other permissions as needed
            });   i am not able to fetch GetLoginUrl from Facebookclient class

Comment: Maybe yor string for `dynamic me` is not correct? Compared to https://gist.github.com/ntotten/4341111 - this implementation only takes the client emai..
And one other thing: You should anonymize your client Id and your client secret in this question. Looks like these are "real" values...